# OpenCL (Intel Platform) shows build error(-11) with status 0

Tags: c++, opencl, intel, nvidia, amd-processor

In Intel platform and Intel SDK compiler clBuildProgram returns CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE clGetProgramBuildInfo shows status as 0. But the AMD and NVIDIA platforms will not produce any error for the same code when building with their SDK and compiler.
The program build log is shown below

```
OPENCL ERROR : CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
Build failed; error=-11, status=0, programLog:
Compilation started
Compilation done
Linking started
Linking done
Kernel <Kernel1> was successfully vectorized
```

The available platforms and devices are
 1. FULL_PROFILE - OpenCL 1.2  - Intel(R) OpenCL - Intel(R) Corporation
     1. Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz - OpenCL 1.2 (Build 76413)
     2. Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 - OpenCL 1.2

Operating System is Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Can you post the code that produces that? What is the status flag? It looks everything is ok with the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is because of

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64: enable
```

if I comment this and made the double to float then clBuildProgram will return success. But by enabling this gives the output.